# Upgrade from angular 8.2 to angular 9 issue

Tags: javascript, angular, npm, angular-upgrade, angular9

When Upgrading from angular 8.2 to angular 9 I got this error

> An unhandled exception occurred: Cannot find module '@angular-devkit/schematics'

How can I overcome this error?

---

this is the used command:

`ng update @angular/core @angular/cli --next`

Comment: Well simply npm i --save-dev @angular-devkit/schematics before updating?

Comment: if `@angular-devkit/schematics` only exists in `package-lock.json` than deleting this, node_modules and running npm update works

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can overcome this issue when running this command before the update command

`npm i --save-dev @angular-devkit/schematics`

Answer (score 2):

You should update all libraries inside your project. If you want to update libraries one by one, first identify them using the following command:

```sh
ng update
```

Next update the identified packages, for example:

```sh
ng update @angular/core @angular/cli
```

If you want to automatically update all, use the --all and --force switches with the ng udpate command as follows:

```sh
ng update --all --force
```

Check out this [example tutorial](https://www.techiediaries.com/angular/upgrade-angular-8-7-to-angular-9-with-cli-ng-update/).

Answer (score 0):

If you are still looking for updation from angular 8 to 9, just do the following:

```
ng update @angular/core @angular/cli
```

If still some problems exists with dependencies or something else just force all to update:

```
ng update --all --force
```

check your angular version by using:

```
ng --version
```